# Horizontal Scroll View not scrolling the TextView's

Tags: android

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Date/Time"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="BP"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="BP Position"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Body Site"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Laterality / Cuff Size"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="HR"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="RR"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="T(F)"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Wt"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Ht"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="BMI"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="BSA"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="O2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>        

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I have placed my `TextView's` inside a `LinearLayout` which is again under a `HorizontalScrollView`, but i don't see it getting scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your HorizontalListView inside a LinearLayout and pass the tag xlms to LinearLayout and the scroll will work perfectly!